# Pedir datos en typedef de c++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Mi pregunta es acerca  de que el código debe de pedir al usuario que ingrese la clave y nombre del alumno en vez de estar declarados, creo que solo la parte de asignar valores se modifica pero no estoy seguro, agradecería mucho su ayuda, adjunto código

(Esta parte se puede omitir ya que no me deja publicar la pregunta (Por que me dice que agregue mas información pero ya formule la pregunta), ya que es mi primera vez publicando una pregunta y aun no se como funciona muy bien)

```
#include "iostream"
#include <string.h>
#define MAXIMO 3 //Constante
#define TAMANO 20 //Declaración de constantes 

typedef struct persona{
    int clave;
    char nombre[TAMANO];
};

typedef persona TipoElemento;
typedef int posicion;

typedef struct Lista{
TipoElemento elementos [MAXIMO];
posicion ultimo;
};

persona Alumno1, Alumno2, Alumno3;
Lista MiLista;

void AsignarValores (){//Esta es la parte que debo modificar para que pida la clave y el nombre del alumno en vez de estar declaradas 
     Alumno1.clave=001;
     strcpy(Alumno1.nombre,"Juanito");//Asignar valores a un vector
     Alumno2.clave=002;
     strcpy(Alumno2.nombre,"Oscar");
     Alumno3.clave=003;
     strcpy (Alumno3.nombre,"Perez");
     MiLista.elementos[0]=Alumno1;
     MiLista.elementos[1]=Alumno2;
     MiLista.elementos[2]=Alumno3;
}

void Imprimir (){
   for (int i=0; i<MAXIMO; i++){
      printf("ELEMENTO[%d]:\n",i);
      printf("Clave=%d\n",MiLista.elementos[i].clave);
      printf("Nombre=%s\n",MiLista.elementos[i].nombre);
      }
}

main(){
    AsignarValores();
    Imprimir();
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido! Te recomiendo que te des una vuelta por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que ganes tu primera medalla. Es muy importante que revises [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), tu pregunta no expresa un problema puntual... ¿Qué problema tienes?¿Qué dudas tienes?¿Qué reto enfrentas?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Hola, ya modifique la publicación a ver si queda mas clara la pregunta (Modificar la función AsignarValores para que la información de los tres alumnos sean introducida por el usuario.), agradecería tu ayuda por favor

Answer (score 0):

En C++, lo que debes hacer para pedir datos al usuario es usar el objeto `cin` que se encuentra en `<iostream>` (aunque no te de error, es preferible no usar comillas para headers estándar de C++, sólo con los tuyos).

Una consecuencia de esto es que en lugar de usar un array de chars `char nombre[MAXIMO]`, es mucho más recomendable usar la clase estándar para este tipo de uso de guardar y manipular texto: `std::string`, del header(o "archivo de cabecera") `<string>`. Esto tiene la ventaja extra de que el nombre puede ser de cualquier tamaño.

Así que, tendrías que hacer estos cambios:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> //No siempre es necesario, a veces <iostream> ya incluye <string>
//<string> no es lo mismo que <string.h>

typedef struct persona {
    int clave;
    std::string nombre;
}

//...

void AsignarValores(){
    std::cout << "Escribe la clave: ";
    std::cin >> Alumno1.clave
    std::cout << "Escribe el nombre: ";
    std::cin >> Alumno1.nombre;
    //...
    //Y así con los otros dos alumnos
}
```

Bueno, eso es la respuesta. Ahora, no es por criticar, pero se ve que tu código se parece mucho más a C que a C++ y estas son algunas sugerencias.

- Como mencionaba, iostream se incluye como `<iostream>`
- Usa `<string>` y `std::string` en lugar de arrays de chars
- No es necesario escribir `typedef struct persona` basta con `struct persona`. Igual con `struct Lista { ...`
- En C++, `struct` y `class` es lo mismo, sólo cambia el nivel de acceso por default de lo que hay adentro(funciones/métodos y variables). En `struct` todo es `public` por defecto.
- Muchos aún usan typedef para hacer algo como `typedef persona TipoElemento;`, pero la manera moderna de hacer esto en C++ es `using TipoElemento = persona;`
- Según mi experiencia, en C++ la convención es que los nombres de variables y funciones empiezan con minúscula y las clases/structs empiezan con mayúscula
- Esta línea: `Alumno1.clave=001;` es un error. El error es que cualquier literal de número que empiece con un 0, representa un número octal, así que si en lugar de 001 fuera 009, sería un error de compilación, y si fuera un 013, en realidad sería el 11 decimal. Así que la línea, sin ese error, quedaría así: `Alumno1.clave=1`
- En `Imprimir()`, usas varios printf. Si es preferencia personal, está bien, pero podrías usar el objeto de salida a consola de C++: `cout`. Como ejemplo, la línea `printf("ELEMENTO[%d]:\n",i)`, quedaría como `cout << "ELEMENTO[" << i << "]\n";`. Como puedes ver, con `cout` no tienes que estar especificando el tipo de dato de lo que quieres mostrar, es bastante "typesafe".
- Si quieres usar printf con variables tipo std::string, entonces tendrías que poner algo así: `std::string mi_var = "texto"; printf("Mi variable: %s", mi_var.c_str());`
- Tal vez hayas notado el uso de `std::` al utilizar un `cin`, `cout`, o `string`. Eso es un namespace, el de la librería estándar de C++, a la que pertenecen archivos de cabecera como `<iostream>`, `<string>`, `<fstream>`, etc. Si prefieres ahorrarte el tener que poner `std::` antes de cada `cout`, `cin`, o `string`, puedes poner esto después de tus includes, o de preferencia, como la primera línea de tu función `main`: `using namespace std;`
- Y por último, en C++ tu función main debería ser al menos `int main()`, no sólo `main()`, y tampoco `void main()`. Y si quieres ser más estricto, puedes escribirlo así: `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`. Pero al menos debe llevar ese `int` al principio. Supongo que el poder omitirlo es por compatibilidad con C. La falta de `return` en el `main` no importa, es normal aunque se especifique el tipo de retorno de `main` como `int`.